# System restarts with SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION error when launching docker desktop

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am experiencing an issue with Docker Desktop on my Windows system. Every time I try to launch Docker Desktop, my system crashes and restarts, displaying a "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION" error. This problem consistently occurs, and I am unable to use Docker as a result.

Here are the details of my system and the error:

Operating System: Windows 10
Docker Desktop Version: 4.25.0
Error Message: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
I have attached a screenshot of the error for reference.

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling Docker Desktop and checking for any system updates, but the issue persists.